# delete records which are selected from select query on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to delete few records which I got from a subquery.

Let's say that the `EMP` table has columns `EMPNAME`, `EMPSALARY` and the primary key is a combination of `EMPNAME,EMPSALARY`.

```
delete from emp 
where exists (
        select * 
        from EMP ***** //query which fetch few records from EMP table);
```

The above query is not working.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hard to say for sure without the whole query but I suspect your subquery is not correlated. Why are doing your delete like this instead just a straight delete? Also, are you using sql server or oracle? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Why aren't you just doing a delete with the same where as the subquery? Do you really need the `exists` at all?

Comment: Also what sort of PK is employe name and salary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query would look something like

```
delete from emp 
from  emp e
where exists (select * 
              from EMP 
              WHERE e.EMPNAME = EMPNAME
               AND  e.EMPSALARY = EMPSALARY 
               AND  <another Condition>)   --<-- Condition on which you want to delete rows
```

Comment: DELETE FROM EMP E1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT E2 FROM EMP E2 WHERE E1.EMPNAME = US2.EMPNAME and E1.EMPSALARY = '100' AND E2.EMPSALARY = '1000'); This query is working fine with ORACLE DB but not Working with MSSQL. Can you please help me writing generic query which works with ORACLE and MSSQL.

Answer (score 3):

you can directly give condition in where clause

```
delete from emp where <conditions>;
```

else you can do in this way

```
DELETE FROM Table1 T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT column1 FROM table2 T2
               WHERE T1.column1 = T2.column1 
                 AND T1.Column2 = T2.column2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below query:

```
delete from emp 
where primary_key_column_name IN 
  (
     select primary_key_column_name from EMP where <your conditions>
  );
```

or

```
delete from emp where <your conditions>;
```

Comment: Which is the same as `delete from emp where <your conditions>`